# Why the units of surface tension are force per unit length?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

I do not understand surface tension concept. I read explanations from many sources but I still do not get the units that it has.

The units of surface tension are $N/m = J/m^2$. Let's define the surface of a 3D fluid as $z=f(x,y)$. So the surface tension acts parallel to the surface but my intuitive idea is that the units should be $N/m^2$ and not $N/m$, I do not get why is per unit length? I do not understand how you get a "unit length" on a 2D surface.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surface tension can be thought of the energy input needed to create new surface area. In that sense the unit $\left[\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m^2}\right]$ makes sense.

For the force concept, consider a spherical liquid droplet in air. Since it is completely spherical, we can describe its air/liquid interface in spherical coordinates as a circle. As surface tension only acts at the interface (i.e. the circle) we can consider it a force per unit length (of the circle). When the droplet grows, i.e. creates more surface area, the circle grows and the force grows too.

Comment: Please, could you explain why the solid/liquid interface can be considered a line?

Comment: @DOMiguel - I have revised my answer, hopefully it make more sense this way? I have to say i find it easier to understand (and explain) it in terms of energies.